# Is it possible to use macOS 'Keychain' + 'TouchID' for pinentry-program?

Tags: macos, gnupg, pgp, openpgp, yubikey

Is there some way of configuring `pinentry-mac`, which I currently use to enter the passphrase for my OpenPGP card (a Yubikey), or a different program that'll store the passphrase in the macOS 'Keychain', so that I just have to use 'TouchID' rather than type it out?

Comment: See the article [Set up Keybase.io, GPG & Git to sign commits on GitHub](https://github.com/pstadler/keybase-gpg-github) and especially the section "Optional: In case you're prompted to enter the password every time" which describes using gpg-agent with pinentry-mac.

Comment: Post seems to be dead.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking into something similar (minus the Yubikey) and found out that pinentry-mac does not support Touch ID (not yet at least). I ended up writing [`pinentry-touchid`](https://github.com/jorgelbg/pinentry-touchid) a "wrapper"/integration around pinentry-mac that asks confirmation (via Touch ID) when retrieving the password from the macOS Keychain.

I do not currently have a Yubikey, but [`pinentry-touchid`](https://github.com/jorgelbg/pinentry-touchid) speaks the assuan IPC protocol to communicate with the gpg-agent. I'm guessing that it should work in this case as well. If something doesn't work, feel free to open an issue.

Comment: Nice! (9 ch to go)